# Should MVC Partial Views be used in Single Page Applications using a framework like Angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'm just picking up Angular 2 using ASP.NET Core. Only having experience with MVVM with WPF, I'm seeing lots of the same concepts, but there's a lot of new stuff.

The HTML template is the view, like I'm used to. I'd say the TypeScript Component fills the role of ViewModel, translating model to properties bound to in the View. Angular looks pretty MVVM to me with it's binding. I'm comfortable with that.

I'm seeing some conflict of interests with ASP.NET and Angular2 though. ASP has html views, but for the moment all I've got is a simple index page that holds the Angular App component. It also has ASP.NET controllers, which at the moment' I'm just using to serve data to the Angular2 Components.

My question is, should I be using ASP Partial Views (.cshtml) as the templates for my Angular components, if I'm using Angular 2 Routing? I've been looking at [this tutorial](https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/), which does so. Is there any advantage to this?

I could make the single page application section of the site almost completely separate from the rest of the web-pages served using traditional ASP MVC. I'm not sure whether I should be mashing them together arbitrarily.

Where does the responsibility of Angular end and ASP begin?

Should I be using .NET Controllers like this:

```
    http.get('/api/Chat/GetChatMessages').subscribe(result => {
        this.chatMessages = result.json();
    });
```

and:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ChatController
{
    private List<ChatMessage> messages = new List<ChatMessage>();

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<ChatMessage> GetChatMessages()
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

Or wrapping them in an Angular Service?

Comment: I would say no, because using files with .cshtml extension will go through the razor rendering engine. If you used plain html you would get a faster render time, because there is no need for IIS to force it through any rendering engine.

Comment: Is this question still up to date ? 
You shouldn't use CSHTML to do an SPA for the exact reason @gh9 mentionned, but you can if you want, as you are able to link your Angular2 components to partial views.
My advice is that you should use Angular2 components to do your views and your models, and then if needed make http calls to your .NET controllers if you need to.

I can fill in some examples in an answer is this is still up to date.